# What is the messaging contract of QuickFIX/J? Do I get guaranteed in order delivery?

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixj

I am just getting started with QuickFIX/J. One thing I am confused reading their documents is that what exactly is the messaging contract ensured by QuickFIX implementation of the FIX protocol?

In particular, I know FIX has a built-in sequence number based mechanism which implementations can leverage to handle out of order, missing or duplicated messages. But does QuickFIX/J already has the capability built in? As an application using QuickFIX/J to communicate with a fix engine, can I assume:

1. Messages delivered to my app from QuickFIX/J are always in order.
2. There is no missing messages (QuickFIX/J will automatically handle
   the re-requesting)
3. There is no duplicated messages (QuickFIX/J can
   look at the sequence number recieved so far and filter out possible
   duplication)
4. If the remote fix engine crashes, I will reconnect with the last known sequence number automatically when the engine comes back
5. If my app crashes, when it restarts will it be able to automatically resume the session from the previous known sequence number? (e.g. will there be any out of the box sequence number persistence mechanism?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QuickFIX/J implements the FIX session protocol, so it handles all the session-level stuff (connecting, sequence numbers, ...) for you.

1. Yes, but there may be duplicates, see 3.
2. Yes.
3. No, actually QFJ will still forward possible duplicates to your app because you still might want to handle those. You need to filter them by yourself if you want to, based on `43/PossDupFlag`.
4. Yes.
5. Yes. QFJ has some out of the box persistence mechanisms like `FileStore`, `JdbcStore`, `MemoryStore`. You could also implement your own `Store` if you need to.

Here is a link on how to create a QFJ application, in case you haven't already found it: https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj#creating-a-quickfixj-application

Comment: Cool, thanks. You are absolutely right that QuickFIX/J has the session management handling fully baked in. Is it common for application to overwrite the seq number upon a restart? QuickFIX/J stores the received seq number synchronously once it dispatches the message to the application. But if I move the messages to a different queue,they are not considered "handled" until the worker thread reads from that queue. I can keep track of the seq number at the other end of the queue manually, but how can I give my seq number to QuickFIX/J when my app recovers from a crash?

Comment: You need to use the message store to set the next expected sequence number(s). Take care that you change the value before initiating/accepting the next Logon. You can use `Session.setNextTargetMsgSeqNum(int)` or `Session.setNextSenderMsgSeqNum(int)`

Comment: I came to realize after some testing that not all admin messages are delivered to application layer in-order. I am particularly confused about the behavior around Logon reply where message replay is needed. Logon *reply* is always delivered (`fromAdmin` method) the moment it is received, and then the resent messages follow. This means my app will see the Logon reply seq num first (which is higher than expected), and resent seq num afterwards. More surprisingly, at the end of the replay there is a SeqReset with GapFill to skip over the Logon reply. it is not delivered to application at all?

Comment: I need to look in the source to be sure but there are some messages which are forwarded in any case regardless of their sequence number. Logon and logout for example. The Logon reply is skipped because session level messages are not resent (except the Reject message). Do you really need to consider admin messages?

Comment: I understand why the receiver sends a SeqReset to skip the Logon reply. But I thought my app layer should be able to see this SeqReset. What happened is that Logon reply (with seq=10) is received and delivered to app, and then **queued**. Afterwards message resent for seq 7, 8, 9 happens, and then this queued Logon message is processed to advance the targetSeqNum to 10 (hence expecting 11). At last the the SeqReset (with seq=10, newSeqNo=11, PossDup=Y) arrives and gets ignored because its seq number is too low: it is 10, but the QuickFIX/J is expecting 11.

Comment: initially I thought I will just look at all the messages received and make a note of their sequence number at my application layer. I don't care about the meaning of the admin messages at the app layer, but in case the connection is idle for a long time (no app message, just heartbeats), I do want to advance my tracked sequence number from time to time in order to not fall behind too far. But if admin messages are not always delivered in order, tracking the seq number of them will be more involved than just retrieving the field. And I would prefer to ignore the admin messages completely.

Comment: Hmm are you sure about that the SeqReset is ignored because its seqnum is too low? Sounds strange to me. Can you upload a log somewhere? What engine does the counterparty use?

Comment: yes, that is what I understand tracing into the source code. The server is a very simple echo server I made using QuickFIX/J as well. Yes I can upload the log somewhere if you believe that is unexpected

Comment: I assume you are using a recent version?

Comment: yup, should be the most recent release version

Comment: My proposal: to make sure that your seqnums are in sync, send a `TestRequest` with a unique `TestReqID` (e.g. timestamp) right after Logon. When the `Heartbeat` reply with the matching `TestReqID` is handed to your code then you know that you are in-sync. So you can ignore the admin messages almost completely, except `Heartbeats` with your desired `TestReqID`. Or you could also allow all other `Heartbeats` to advance the tracked seqnums from time to time.